# why would strptime return nanosecond timestamp depending on string formatting

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pandas

Simplified version of the code:

```
df.loc[df.loc['A'].notnull(), 'B'] = df.loc[df.loc['A'].notnull(), 'A'].map(
    lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

> **problem**:
>
> This code populated column 'B' with 19 digit integers (I assume nanosecond Unix time) instead of the expected datetime or pandas Timestamp.

The data frame was read in from a csv created by a MSSQL Server export. The date format in the file did not have padded zeros. That shouldn't be a problem, but when the file was reformatted the *column then populated with timestamps as expected*.

We found a pretty easy work around, but I can't find any documentation that would explain why strptime would return an integer and I can't reproduce this behavior when I run it entering values in a console (or Jupyter).

Q1: What's going on here?

Q2: Could string formatting from MSSQL somehow produce this behavior?

Q3: Should we just count our blessings and stop asking why?

I will just note that this was a weird circumstance and a solution was found by adjusting other parts of the code, I would just like to understand what was happening.

(python 2.7, pandas 0.18)

Comment: Do you have some data to go with that code?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have data accessible to me now (from home) the values in column "A" were all strings and formatted like "m/d/yyyy" when it didn't work and "mm-dd-yyyy" when it did.